# Use of sql-statement result in other sql-statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to use the id I'm getting from the prior sql-statement to fetch the table information for that id, but `$query3` always returns `FALSE` and I can't seem to figure out. I am connected to the database and I do have the permissions to access this table. The id is also correct in each case.

**CODE**

```
global $con;
$query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM allTeams WHERE Coach = ?");
$query->bind_param('s',$username);
$query->execute();
$query->bind_result($Id,$time,$day,$coach,$hCoach);

$date = date('d-m');
$array = array();

while($row = $query -> fetch())
{
    var_dump($Id);
    echo "<br />";
    $teamId = strval($Id);
    $query3 = $con -> query("DESCRIBE `$teamId`");
    var_dump($query3);
    echo "<br />";
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
int(1022) 
bool(false) 
int(1023) 
bool(false) 
int(2033) 
bool(false)
```

Comment: Do you really have  table called `1022`?  Also, you're missing a back-tick: ``$con->query("DESCRIBE `$teamId`");``

Comment: Yes. I added the back-tick, but the output is still the same.

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do?  Do you *really* have a table called `1022`?  What are you trying to `DESCRIBE`?  Why are you using the id?  What is your goal here?  What *should* the output be?

Comment: I need to know the fields in the tables. Yes, I really have an table called 1022. The type of the id is a varchar(255). The output should the the fields of the tables.

Comment: Add `if($query3 === FALSE){ echo $con->error; }`, and see what it prints.

Comment: It prints: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Comment: @RocketHazmat Thank you. I've deleted my answer following further details from the OP. I read the square brackets from the syntax definition, Doh! But I believe it can describe fields of tables.

Comment: This has made me kind of curious. Why a table with a number?

Comment: I was supplied with a table, which contain fields, which contain all the other tables (the number) along with other information. The number is the only unique information, so I'm using this information to find my table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to run a query on the same `$con` object, while one is already open.  You can't do that.

What you need to do is call `store_result` to close the first query before you can run new ones.

```
global $con;
$query = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM allTeams WHERE Coach = ?");
$query->bind_param('s',$username);
$query->execute();
$query->store_result();
$query->bind_result($Id,$time,$day,$coach,$hCoach);

$date = date('d-m');
$array = array();

while($row = $query -> fetch())
{
    var_dump($Id);
    echo "<br />";
    $teamId = strval($Id);
    $query3 = $con -> query("DESCRIBE `$teamId`");
    var_dump($query3);
    echo "<br />";
}
```